# delphi kbmmw delete a record doesn't work

Tags: delphi

I try to delete record with kbmmw componet.

I use TkbmMWClientQuery on client side.

First way.

Functions

```
TkbmMWClientQuery.Append/Post;
TkbmMWClientQuery.Resolve;
```

are work but

```
TkbmMWClientQuery.Delete;
TkbmMWClientQuery.Resolve;
```

doesn't work

Second way.

I made separate qSEL_COMP_DEL query on server side with parameters

sql code:

```
delete from Company_Users Where  Phone_main = :PPhone_main and ID_Comp_Users = :PID_Comp_Users
```

And run it on client side.

```
    if qSEL_COMP_DEL.Active then
       qSEL_COMP_DEL.Close;

 qSEL_COMP_DEL.ParamByName['PPhone_Main'].AsString := qSEL_COMP.FieldByName('Phone_main').AsString;
 qSEL_COMP_DEL.ParamByName['PID_COMP_USERS'].AsInteger := qSEL_COMP.FieldByName('ID_Comp_Users').AsInteger;

 qSEL_COMP_DEL.Query.Text:='@SEL_COMP_DEL';
 qSEL_COMP_DEL.Execute; // .Open;
 qSEL_COMP_DEL.Resolve;
```

It also doesn't work.

How  to solve a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable server side debug to see what it generates for your delete statement.

On the server, somewhere before you attempt to resolve:

```
kbmMWDebugTypes:=[mwdtDBResolve];
kbmMWDebugWhere:=mwddOneRawTextFile;
kbmMWDebugLevel:=[mwdlAll];
kbmMWDebugFile:='c:\temp\debug.txt';
```

It will output the SQL generated and the result(s) for your resolve.

Also remember that if you insert a record in a client query, and then delete it, it wont be inserted/deleted during a resolve, as it, seen from the servers view, never have existed in the first place.

However since your manual statement also do not work, I assume its actually your database that prevents you from deleting. Perhaps referential integrity has been enabled, and prevents you from deleting a master record before its detail records have been removed first.

best regards
Kim/C4D